# How to construct a graph with six vertices that has the chromatic number 4 (not 3)?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

I have a question related to graph theory. First, I want to state that I am not a mathematician or computer scientist, but a psychologist doing research on cognitive processing related to computer science concepts.

We plan conducting a study with human participants on scheduling problems with graph visualizations as aids for solving the problems. I am currently working on generating the material, i.e. the graphs that underlie the problems.

In psychological experiments we always aim at keeping as many properties of the material constant (controlled) as possible. In this case, we want to restrict the experiment to graphs with 6 vertices and around 8 edges to have some managable complexity of the problems for laypeople.

Now, those graphs are probably all going to be planar and my attempts in manually constructing them all the time result in graphs that have the chromatic number 3 which might be "boring" for participants after a few examples, so I would like to learn what is required to construct graphs with 6 vertices and chromatic number 4.
Are simply more edges necessary? (Ideally, the graphs would not be disconnected.)
Do I have to include K4 as a subgraph?

In German Wikipedia I found some statement that roughly translate to this: "What is the chromatic number of a planar graph? The four-color theorem states that the chromatic number of a planar graph is at most 4. If the graph does not contain a triangle, it is even 3-node colorable."
What is a triangle in this sense? 3 nodes connected by lines (forming a triangle in the geometric sense) can't be right ... Is it rather K4?

I would be very grateful for some helpful hints regarding my problem.

As illustrative examples of what I have tried so far see the following:

[image: two planar graphs with 6 vertices]

Both graphs have 6 vertices and 8 edges.
The left graph has several "triangles" and can still be coloured using three colours. The right one requires four colours since it contains K4.

Comment: You might want to check Grötzsch's theorem. A triangle in this instance is three vertices each connected to each other, forming a triangle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch%27s_theorem

Comment: I think what confuses me about this theoreme is the following: It states that every planar graph can be coloured using not more than three colours if it has no triangle. And I think I mistakenly thought this would imply that four colours are required to colour a graph if it contains a triangle, which can be easily proven wrong. So there are still plenty of graphs that are three-colourable even though they contain one or more tirangles, right?

Comment: Yes. However, to get a chromatic number of 4, we are forced to put a triangle. Shame that we cannot put images on comments.

Answer (score 2):

As from Grötzsch's theorem, we need to have a triangle in our graph. The only reason is that we can exploit this by adding another point and connecting it to all of the points of the triangle.

We can see that the configuration below has a chromatic number of 4 and consists of 4 points:[image: Open this image in a new tab]

You now can add 2 extra points to get a total of 6 points, adding any configuration you want.

For example,

[image: Open the image in a new tab]

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense and is very helpful! So according to this, I need to include K4 as subgraph, right?

Comment: It is not actually K4. ALthough they make look similar, when you try to connect another point to it, one dot is inaccessible in this instance, while you can access all 4 in a K4 graph.

Comment: So it's the planar embedding of K4, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the embedding of K4.

Comment: @MarBor It is not necessary to have $K_4$ as a subgraph. For example, [this graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=204) has chromatic number $4$ even though it has no $K_4$.

Comment: I see, thanks! Great website you linked there - that appears to be very useful for me.